# Recover IIS Express build files

Tags: visual-studio, iis-7.5

Ive made a terrible mistake and decided to make the publish folder for a VS Solution the folder of the source files.
Selecting the delete previous files prior I have removed majority of the source I was working on.
It was a small project to do a database integrity cleanse after there was a major bug found through my companies software so there is no Source Control or anything set up and had been a couple days work.

Wondering if IIS express stores a cache of these files anywhere in case I am able to restore the binaries and some other files from a previous build straight back into my source.

Banging my head.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: Nope in all cases. IIS Express is not a source control system and the cache is gone. You might check if something remains in ASP.NET cache. With all those open source tools such as Git, it is horrible that you don't have source control in place.

Comment: Agreed! For a one use throw away project, i thought why waste time in source controlling it. Now i know why.